# Is it possible to use the regular Brisk Menu with a Mutiny desktop in Ubuntu MATE 20.04?

Tags: customization, ubuntu-mate

I'm trying to personalize my desktop in Ubuntu MATE 20.04. I'd like to use a Mutiny (MATE's Unity-style) panel, but with the regular Brisk Menu available in other panel layouts. The trouble is, when using a Mutiny panel, the Brisk Menu transforms into a simulacra of the old Ubuntu Dash. Is there a way to prevent this while still maintaining the Mutiny panel?